# Portforwarding to EC2 instance using ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created an ELB servicing a single EC2 instance. The sole purpose is to allow portforwarding to a web api. The health check ticks along without any visible issues and the ELB status is "In Service". When I access the api through the ELB the performance is very very poor taking 50 secs to return data that direct, using EC2 address, is ALWAYS returned instantly. About 1 in 10 attempts I get an instant return using ELB. Load is minimal and in this pre-production instance I am the only one using it. I assume this can't be normal behaviour if it is what other way can you portforward to an EC2 instance - if not what should I check to improve performance?

Clive.

Comment: Are you sure that your instance is *always* "In service" in your ELB? What can happen is that the instance status is constantly changing between healthy and unhealthy. And when i'ts unhealthy, the ELB will wait for the instance to be healthy and depending on your healthcheck rules, that could be around 50s?

Comment: It was timing out at 30 secs - the default. I extended timeout to 60 secs and the API returns at around 50 secs. It doesn't timeout anymore. I can hammer the API through the EC2 address and get instantaneous response each and every request.  IAre you suggesting the displayed status will only ch

Comment: look at the cloudwatch metrics for the ELB, in particular BackendConnectionErrors, Latency, UnHealthyHostCount, HTTPCode_BackEnd_5XX.  If they seem ok, then maybe the problem is with access to the ELB itself.  Check DNS

Comment: @Vorsprung - Thanks for pointing me at CloudWatch metrics. Not looked at it before. Everything backend looks good. How do you suggest I check the ELB DNS? It resolves but doesn't respond to ping.

Comment: ELB does not respond to pings, by design.